# Using not exists in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, not-exists

I have two tables.

```
Doctype
-----------
doctypeid 
doctype 

DocumentList
-----------------
doclistid (pk), 
projectid, 
doctypeid, 
docfile(binary)
```

I want to get all the `projectid` and `doctypeid` from `documentlist` table where list of `doctypeid` (from `Doctype` table) does not exist in `DocumentList` table.

Comment: Are you asserting you want all doctypeid from a table where doctypeid not in the table?

Comment: there are plenty of examples of how to do this if you search first: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+not+exists

Comment: Doctypeid is the master list. DocumentList table contains multiple documents with doctypeid. I want to get all doctypeids that are not in document list table. So that I can caution the user that these documents are still missing.

Comment: Table names corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you might want to use something like this:

```
SELECT projectid, doctypeid
FROM DocumentList 
WHERE doctypeid NOT in(1,2,3,4...n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  MD.projectid ,
        MD.doctypeid
FROM    my_DocumentList MD
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Mdt.doctypeid
                     FROM   MY_Doctype Mdt
                     WHERE  doctypeid IN ( SELECT   MD.doctypeid ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the list of `projectid` and `doctypeid` from `DocumentList` that its doctypeid  is not exists in `Doctype` use this:

```
SELECT 
    projectid, 
    doctypeid
FROM 
    DocumentList
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
               FROM Doctype 
               WHERE Doctype.doctypeid = DocumentList.doctypeid)
```